# How to validate post data if it exists with Django rest api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a front end built with Angular 9 and a django rest api to capture the email for a subscription form.

I would to validate the entry from the frontend to make sure it does not exist in the database before it is saved if it does not exsit.

here is the model:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

The view set:

```
class EmailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Email.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailSerializer

    def create (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        queryset = models.Email.objects.filter(email=request.data)
        if queryset.exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email exist!')
        serializer.save(email=request.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply mark the `email` field as [**`unique=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#unique):

```
class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The serializers in the Django REST framework take uniqness into acount and will check if an `Email` with the given `email` already exists. Furthermore the uniqness is also enforced at the *database* level, so normally if the database works properly it is impossible to create a second record with the same `email` value.

In the serializer you can specify the error message with:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class EmailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[
        UniqueValidator(
            queryset=Email.objects.all(),
            message='Such email address already exists'
        )]
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Ok. thats nice and how would i return the error message on the angular front end for an end user @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @namdi: you can specify the message in the serializer, see edit.